# jQuery cycle plugin: Getting pager to transition within a mixed content slideshow div

Tags: jquery-plugins, cycle, pager, transition

I have been experiment with Malsup's awesome jQuery cycle plugin and have hit a bit of a snag. I have been using mixed content in my transition div which has worked out fine. The problem occurs when I use pager within the transition divs. Essentially I would like the pager links to transition along with each div so I included the pager div within each transition div.

$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#slider').cycle  ({
            fx:     'scrollLeft', 
            timeout: 10000,
            speed: 500,
            pager: '#pager'
        });
    });




            
                IMAGE
                TEXT
                TEXT
                TEXT
                
                    Try It Now!Terms & Conditions Apply
                
                a

```
        <!-- Content Display 1 -->
        <div id="cs_1" class="show_content clearb">
            <div class="">IMAGE</div>
            <div class="helv reg all" style="width: 500px; font-size: 20px; padding: 0px 0px 10px 0px; color: #ff3e34;">TEXT</div>
            <div class="helv reg all" style="width: 500px; font-size: 25px; padding: 0px 0px 15px 0px;">TEXT</div>
            <div class="helv reg all" style="width: 500px; font-size: 18px; padding: 0px 0px 15px 0px;">TEXT</div>
            <div class="button gradient3" style="height: 57px; width: 180px; margin-top: 20px;">
                <a href ="signup.php"><div id="tryitnow">Try It Now!</div><div id="terms">Terms & Conditions Apply</div></a>
            </div>
            <div id="pager" style="z-index: 200; width: 200px; height: 1px; position: relative; top: -70px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px; left: 310px;">b</div>
        </div>
        <!-- Content Display 1 -->

        <!-- Content Display 2 -->
        <div id="cs_2" class="show_content clearb">
            <div class="">IMAGE</div>
            <div class="helv reg all" style="width: 500px; font-size: 20px; padding: 0px 0px 10px 0px; color: #ff3e34;">TEXT</div>
            <div class="helv reg all" style="width: 500px; font-size: 25px; padding: 0px 0px 15px 0px;">TEXT</div>
            <div class="helv reg all" style="width: 500px; font-size: 18px; padding: 0px 0px 15px 0px;">TEXT</div>
            <div class="button gradient3" style="height: 57px; width: 180px; margin-top 26px;">
                <a href ="signup.php"><div id="tryitnow">Try It Now!</div><div id="terms">Terms & Conditions Apply</div></a>
            </div>
            <div id="pager" style="z-index: 200; width: 200px; height: 1px; position: relative; top: -70px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px; left: 310px;"></div>
        </div>
        <!-- Content Display 2 -->

        <!-- Content Display 3 -->
        <div id="cs_3" class="show_content clearb">
            <div class="">IMAGE</div>
            <div class="helv reg all" style="width: 500px; font-size: 20px; padding: 0px 0px 10px 0px; color: #ff3e34;">TEXT</div>
            <div class="helv reg all" style="width: 500px; font-size: 25px; padding: 0px 0px 15px 0px;">TEXT</div>
            <div class="helv reg all" style="width: 500px; font-size: 18px; padding: 0px 0px 15px 0px;">TEXT</div>
            <div class="button gradient3" style="height: 57px; width: 180px; margin-top 18px;">
                <a href ="signup.php"><div id="tryitnow">Try It Now!</div><div id="terms">Terms & Conditions Apply</div></a>
            </div>
            <div id="pager" style="z-index: 200; width: 200px; height: 1px; position: relative; top: -70px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px; left: 310px;"></div>
        </div>
        <!-- Content Display 3 -->
```

The pager shows up fine on the first slide and transitions out exactly the way I want it to, it does not appear on the following three transitions although the test letters i put in the first two pager divs do. What is it that I am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Well after a bit more experimentation the fix was surprisingly simple but also had an odd result. All I did was supply a second parm to the pager call:

$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#slider').cycle  ({
            fx:     'scrollLeft', 
            timeout: 10000,
            speed: 500,
            pager: '#pager, #pager2'
        });
    });

I renamed the pager on my second slide to pager2 and voila! However something odd happened, the slider appeared on the two subsequent panels that I had NOT renamed! When there was only one parm in pager they did not appear despite all having been named #pager. Once I added the second parm #pager2, all of the controls named #pager that had not appeared before now seem to be appearing. Removing the second parm reverts it back to the state where only the first set of controls appeared. Odd, but working so I'm not complaining.